# "Unknown URL" when integrating Facebook connect with a GAE application

Tags: google-app-engine, facebook

I am trying to integrate facebook with a GAE application. When I go to the page where the facebook login button is I get an alert box with the message "Unknown url".  Is this a configuration issue?  How can I resolve this?

My Java Code:

```
    private static final String ApiKey = "xxxxxxxxx";    
    private FBCore fbCore = GWT.create(FBCore.class);    
    private boolean status = true;
    private boolean xfbml = true;
    private boolean cookie = true;

...

        fbCore.init(ApiKey, status, cookie, xfbml);
```

In my HTML I have

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

In my facebook application I set the site url to something like:

site url:  http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyApplication.html?
canvas url: http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyApplication.html?

Looking at IE I see this error generated:

> Message: OAuth2 specification states that 'perms' should now be called
>   'scope'.  Please update. Line: 23 Char: 1336 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes:

1. You are not authenticating your GAE (server) app with Facebook. To do this you should use [server-side flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).
2. What you are doing is using [GwtFB](https://github.com/olams/GwtFB) (I assume), which is a wrapper around Facebook javascript client library. This library implements [client-side flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#client-side-flow), where only client (js app in browser) is authenticated against Facebook.
3. Unfortunately FB does not have a library that implements server-side flow (as this would be server-technology dependent and there are just too much server technologies around to support them all). For a GAE implementation see [LeanEngine](http://www.lean-engine.com/), specifically the [`FacebookLoginServlet.java`](https://github.com/leanengine/LeanEngine-Server/blob/master/lean-server-lib/src/main/java/com/leanengine/server/auth/FacebookLoginServlet.java) and [`FacebookAuth`](https://github.com/leanengine/LeanEngine-Server/blob/master/lean-server-lib/src/main/java/com/leanengine/server/auth/FacebookAuth.java).
4. With server-side flow, you need to register your 'redirect-after-authentication' url with  Facebook. So you can not use dev server with private addresses (127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.1, etc..). You need a internet visible address.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Peter. does this mean that only server-side works with GAE + Facebook? Should I use something else other than GwtFB when working with my GAE application?

Comment: No, but you need a server-side flow if you need to authenticate user against your GAE server.